# PowerBI - Cannot change database user credentials to other account

Tags: powerbi

**Is there a way to "log out" of account permissions for a linked database on PowerBI, in order to switch to another database account?**

*-obviously tried googling it already, looked through PowerBI forums-*

> Example:
>
> I have linked BigQuery to PowerBI on 123@gmail.com.
>
> I wish to log out of this and access data from account 456@gmail.com instead.

Problem: There isn't a 'log out' button.

There has to be a better way than uninstalling + reinstalling it every time I want to access data from another account. That's nuts.

**What's the best way to do this?**

If it's relevant: I'm on the free desktop version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Options -> Data Source Settings.

Right click on a data source then edit the permissions

Comment: Think my version is different from yours, I used Data Source Settings > Edit > Query Editor > Clear connections. But thanks, didn't realise I could right click on it. Solved!

Comment: @angsty_robot yeah, it's been a while, but it should be somewhere around there anyway